# SQL query create table with headings

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

Currently I am creating a HTML table with data from one of my SQL tables. However I want to put headings for each column (note: I don't want to use the database headings). How can I do this? Below is my current code without headings:

```
<?php
$searchResults = mysql_query("SELECT customerRefId, suburb, postcode, state FROM customer_seeking");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($searchResults);
?>
<table border="1">
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchResults))
{
echo"<tr><td>$row[customerRefId]</td><td>$row[suburb]</td><td>$row[postcode]</td><td>$row[state]</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: you can put under table <thead> before the loop, or you mean something else?

Comment: Wow that was easy! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey You can use the following code for header:::

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>customer Ref Id</th><th>suburb</th><th>postcode</th><th>state</th></tr>
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchResults))
    {
    echo"<tr><td>$row[customerRefId]</td><td>$row[suburb]</td><td>$row[postcode]</td><td>$row[state]</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added  under table

```
<table border="1">
<th>Test</th>
<th>Test2</th>
```

Comment: You forgot to wrap th in tr, it's required.

Answer (score 0):

Output the header row before the `while` loop.